# myItems.sort works for one Outlook subfolder but doesn't on others

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

The below Excel VBA code works for one subfolder (extracts latest attachment) but when applied to another subfolder it extracts information from the oldest email, not the newest.

Is `myFolder.Items.sort` the right method?

```vb
Sub SaveAttachments_RsConfirmation()
Dim myOlapp As Outlook.Application
Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.Namespace
Dim myFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim myAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
Dim I As Long

Set myOlapp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set myNameSpace = myOlapp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set myFolder = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set myFolder = myFolder.Folders("Rs.Confirmation")

myFolder.Items.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", True

For Each myItem In myFolder.Items
    myFolder.Items.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", True
    If myItem.Attachments.Count <> 0 Then
        For Each myAttachment In myItem.Attachments
            
            I = 1
            myAttachment.SaveAsFile "C:\Del.Gen.v1\Confirmation.Email\" & I & ".txt"
            eSender = myItem.SenderEmailAddress
            dtRecvd = myItem.ReceivedTime
            dtSent = myItem.CreationTime
            sSubj = myItem.Subject
            sMsg = myItem.Body
            
            Exit For
        Next
    End If
Next

Workbooks("Del.Gen.v1.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("A1").Value = eSender
Workbooks("Del.Gen.v1.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("A2").Value = dtRecvd
Workbooks("Del.Gen.v1.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("A3").Value = dtSent
Workbooks("Del.Gen.v1.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("A4").Value = sSubj
Workbooks("Del.Gen.v1.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("A5").Value = sMsg

Debug.Print eSender
Debug.Print dtRecvd
Debug.Print dtSent
Debug.Print sSubj
Debug.Print sMsg

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sorting one `Items` collection, but end up using a completely different object - every time you call `MAPIFolder.Items`, you get back a brand new COM object that has no knowledge of any other instances. Read the items collection once, store it in a variable, then loop through its items:

```
set myItems = myFolder.Items
myItems.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", True
For Each myItem In myItems 
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your feed back Dmitry. very helpful indeed!!

Answer (score 1):

myItems.Sort would be fine.

myFolder.Items.Sort despite documentation you may have seen is not valid.

```
Sub SaveAttachments_RsConfirmation()

Dim myOlapp As Outlook.Application
Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim myFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder

Dim myItems As Outlook.items

Set myOlapp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set myNameSpace = myOlapp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set myFolder = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

Set myFolder = myFolder.folders("Rs.Confirmation")

' Attempt to sort items in the folder
myFolder.items.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", True
Debug.Print myFolder.items(1).Subject

' False should be no different from True
myFolder.items.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", False
Debug.Print myFolder.items(1).Subject

' Create a collection of items
Set myItems = myFolder.items
myItems.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", True
Debug.Print myItems(1).Subject

' False should sort opposite to True
myItems.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", False
Debug.Print myItems(1).Subject

ExitRoutine:
    Set myOlapp = Nothing
    Set myNameSpace = Nothing
    Set myFolder = Nothing
    Set myItems = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you sort the folder, take each item and sort the whole folder again. This is probably not what you mean.

```
myFolder.Items.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", True           ' sort folder

For Each myItem In myFolder.Items                    ' process each item
    myFolder.Items.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", True       ' sort folder again: remove this line
    If myItem.Attachments.Count <> 0 Then
        For Each myAttachment In myItem.Attachments
            I = 1                                     ' shouldn't this be incremented?
```

Note that if `I` is not incremented, all attachements will be placed (replaced)in the same file, so you see only one attachment, which will be the one from the last email in the folder.

I am not sure what your problem/question is. First, I would remove the 2nd sort command. Re-sorting could mess-up the order in which`myItem` is obtained form the collection.

But if you want to go into each sub folder, and sub folder, etcetera, you must develop a recursive procedure that sorts a folder, process each item, if item is a folder, descent into sub folder, sort folderr, etc.

Comment: "Note that if I is not incremented, all attachements will be placed (replaced)in the same file, so you see only one attachment, which will be the one from the last email in the folder." ---- this may very well be my problem Paul, as i have tried many variations and gone round in circles, as you'd experience given my self schoolling in vba :)