# How can I reply to the most recent email?

Tags: vba, outlook

I loop through all the emails on my inbox and stop as soon as I get a hit. I get the oldest one. I'd like to get the most recent one instead.

```vb
Dim objNS As Outlook.Namespace: Set objNS = GetNamespace("MAPI")
Dim olFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Set olFolder = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Dim Item As Object

For Each Item In olFolder.Items
    If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.MailItem Then
        Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem: Set oMail = Item
        If InStr(oMail.Subject, "Whatever") > 0 Then
            'Do something
            Exit For
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Items.Sort` method of the `MAPIFolder` object.

```
Dim objNS As Outlook.Namespace: Set objNS = GetNamespace("MAPI")
Dim olFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Set olFolder = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
olFolder.Items.Sort "ReceivedTime", True  ' Sort items by received date in descending order
Dim Item As Object

For Each Item In olFolder.Items
    If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.MailItem Then
        Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem: Set oMail = Item
        If InStr(oMail.Subject, "Whatever") > 0 Then
            'Do something
            oMail.ReplyAll 
            oMail.Display 'This will open the reply window
            Exit For
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect... IF you don't mind. How would I go about opening a reply window with that hit? I used .replyall but the window doesnt come up

Comment: I tried it and it said that property was unknown

Comment: see the edit, `oMail.Display`'This will open the reply window. In the future create a new question for each case.

Comment: The property name is `ReceivedTime`, not `Received`. Either see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem or take a look at an item with OutlookSpy (https://www.dimastr.com/outspy, I am its author) - click Items button to see all properties and their values.

Comment: I didn't want to create a whole post for that, but will do in the future. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Horaciux - also, `ReplyAll` (just like `Reply` and `Forward`) returns the new item, which the script above ignores, so it needs to be `set newItem = oMail.ReplyAl  newItem.Display`

Comment: I tried it but it still gets the oldest email with "whatever" somewhere in the Subject

Comment: Please show your code. You can edit your question above.

Comment: And make sure you don';t use multiple dot notation - see the comment to my answer.

Comment: @VBAnewbie69 `olFolder.Items` is not sorted for the For loop. You need a sorted collection. See here for more https://stackoverflow.com/a/47558167/1571407

Answer (score 0):

Never loop through all items in a folder, always use `Items.Find/FindNext` (if you want to find one or more items) or `Items.Restrict` (if you want to find all matches).

If you want the items in a particular order, sort them first using `Items.Sort`, e.g., `Items.Sort "ReceivedTime", true`

In you participial case, use a query like the one below. Note that it is on the `PR_NORMALIZED_SUBJECT` MAPI property since it is indexed (unlike `PR_SUBJECT`).

```
@SQL="http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E1D001F" LIKE '%whatever%'
```

The following will do the job:

```
set oItems = olFolder.Items
oItems.Sort "ReceivedTime", true
set oMail = oItems.Find "@SQL=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E1D001F"" LIKE '%whatever%'"
if not (oMail is Nothing) Then
  'Do something
End If
```

Comment: .find is too finicky for my particular use case and I can't really restrict the loop as the items could be anyhwhere on the inbox

Comment: Finicky? I am not aware of any outstanding issues with it. Try the query above. I am also not sure why you can't use Items.Restrict: what do you mean by "the items could be anyhwhere on the inbox"? Well, an item is either in the folder, or it is not. If it is there, Items.Restrict will returns an Items collection with all the matches.

Comment: Tried out and it did run but didn't sort them, it still returns oldest hit using "ReceivedTime"

Comment: Please show your code. Make sure you don't use multiple dot notation (`olFolder.Items.Sort` followed by `olFolder.Items.Find`) - in that case you will be using two independent `Items` objects. Store `olFolder.Items` in a dedicated variable and call `Sort/Find/FindNext` on it.

Comment: I mean finicky in the sense that I need to find if the string is present somewhere in the subject, not that specific string as the subject. However, I'm still a noob so if .find has further functionality I'm willing to learn..

Comment: The SQL query above matches on a substring, not the whole subject. Try it.

Comment: See the updated answer above.